# Execute Script of Chrome extension only once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've made a Chrome script that modifies a specific login Page. It works as expected, but I can see in the console that it is always active, although it should only be applied on the login site.

My manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Login Enhancer",
  "description": "Login without a hassle",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://*.examplesite.io/subdomain/portal/#/login"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.active) {

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'script.js'});

  }
});
```

script.js

```
// delete useless Remember Me Function
document.querySelector('.remember-me').remove();
```

After I've logged in when I'm browsing on `examplesite.io/subdomain` the console says on every new page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null
    at script.js:2
```

Obviously there is no more `remember-me` button to remove. This has probably to do with the Listener in my `background.js` File. What is the correct listener so the `script.js` is only executed once on `https://*.examplesite.io/subdomain/portal/#/login` and not everywhere on `https://*.examplesite.io`?

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: Are you wanting this just for yourself, or are you planning to distribute it on the Chrome store? If you want it just for yourself (and it's not a project intended to introduce yourself to Chrome extensions), you will probably have a better overall experience (writing and using) if you write this as a user-script using [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For what you have shown in the question, the best way to do this is to use a [`content_scripts`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration) entry in your [*manifest.json*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) to load your content script instead of using [`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) to do so. Doing it as a `content_scripts` entry will inject the script once whenever the specified page is loaded. It is significantly less complicated than using `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` for the purpose of loading a script when a URL matches a certain page. In general, `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` should be used when the interaction with the user *begins* with the user clicking on a [browserAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) or [pageAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) button (which you are not using), or when you want more detailed control over when the script is injected other than always once for pages [matching a specific URL, or URL pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) (which you don't need for what you are doing).

In your case, you are wanting to inject the script once, every time a specific URL is loaded. This is exactly the use case for which the `content_scripts` key in *manifest.json* exists.

Given that your background script was doing nothing other than loading your content script, using a `content_scripts` entry means you do not need a background script. In addition, you don't need to explicitly specify `permissions` for that particular URL. Your extension is implicitly given permissions for the URLs which match the  `content_scripts` `matches` key.

You could do this by changing your *manifest.json* to:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Login Enhancer",
  "description": "Login without a hassle",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.examplesite.io/subdomain/portal/#/login"],
      "js": ["script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```